# How many arrangements of 1,1,1,1,2,3,3 are there with 2 not beside either 3?

Tags: combinatorics

How many arrangements of 1,1,1,1,2,3,3 are there with 2 not beside either 3?

If I find this by method of complementation then

Total number of arrangements without any restrictions =$\frac{7!}{4!×2!}$.

Then I should subtract total no of arrangements where 2 is beside either three
That means arrangements with 233,323,332 should be subtracted. if we take 233,323,332 as 3 possibilities then how should I proceed further

Please correct me if I am wrong here.

Comment: The answer that you posted is $0$, so it's probably incorrect. Here's a hint: if you place the $2$ and the $3$'s, the positions of the $1$'s are uniquely determined. Also, notice the difference between the cases where the 2 is "at the edge" and when it's "somewhere in the middle".

Comment: Please check I have already edited

Comment: How many arrangements have $23$? how many have $32$? how many have $323$?

Comment: There are 3×5 such arrangements where 2 is beside either 3 , am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you observed, there are 
$$\binom{7}{4}\binom{3}{2}\binom{1}{1} = \frac{7!}{4!2!1!} = \frac{7!}{4!2!}$$
distinguishable arrangements of four $1$s, one $2$, and two $3$s.  From these, we must exclude those arrangements in which a $3$ is adjacent to the $2$.

*A $3$ is adjacent to the $2$*:  We have six objects to arrange, four $1$s, a $3$, and a block containing a $2$ and a $3$.  We choose four of the six positions for the $1$s, one of the remaining two positions for the $3$, and the final position for the block.  The $2$ and $3$ can be arranged within the block in $2!$ ways.  Hence, the number of such arrangements is 
$$\binom{6}{4}\binom{2}{1}\binom{1}{1} \cdot 2! = \frac{6!}{4!1!1!} \cdot 2! = \frac{6!2!}{4!}$$

However, in counting arrangements in which a $3$ is adjacent to the $2$, we have counted arrangements in which both $3$s are adjacent to the $2$ twice, once when we designated $32$ as our block and once when we designated $23$ as our block.  We only want to subtract such arrangements once.  Therefore, we must add them back.

*Both $3$s are adjacent to the $2$*:  This can only occur if the arrangement includes the block $323$.  Thus, we have five objects to arrange, the four $1$s and the block.  We choose four of those five positions for the $1$s.  The block must be placed in the remaining position.  Hence, there are 
$$\binom{5}{4} = \frac{5!}{4!}$$
such arrangements.

By the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), there are 
$$\binom{7}{4}\binom{3}{2}\binom{1}{1} - \binom{6}{4}\binom{2}{1}\binom{1}{1}2! + \binom{5}{4}\binom{1}{1} = \frac{7!}{4!2!} - \frac{6!2!}{4!} + \frac{5!}{4!} = 50$$
permissible arrangements.

Answer (score 3):

If $2$ is at the left end, or at the right end of the permutation, we can choose $2$ of $5$ spots where we put the the $3$'s, which can be done in ${5}\choose{2}$ ways. If $2$ is in one of the middle $5$ spots, then we can put the $3$'s in $2$ of $4$ different spots, so we can do this in ${4}\choose{2}$ ways. This should give the answer $$2 \cdot {{5}\choose{2}} + 5 \cdot {{4}\choose{2}} = 50.$$

Comment: Is this your final answer? I am not getting you.

Comment: Yes. The $2$ in $2 \cdot {{5}\choose{2}}$ is because $2$ can be either at the left end, or at the right end of the arrangement, and the $5$ in $5 \cdot {{4}\choose{2}}$ is for the middle $5$ spots.

Comment: @KavitaSahu  If $2$ is at the end, there are five positions not adjacent to the $2$, so Matija is selecting two of them for the $3$s.  If $2$ is in one of the middle $5$ positions, there are $4$ positions not adjacent to the $2$, so Matija is selecting $4$ of them for the $3$s.

Answer (score 2):

Now that we have established that the three possibilities. We check how many ways we can place them into the rest of your list 
$$\_1\_1\_1\_1\_$$

Note how there are $5$ different places to place your three possibilities. That means in total you have $15$ permutations with the 2 next to a 3.

EDIT:
As mentioned in the comments, this is incorrect. We did not take into account the possibility of only $23$ occurring in a slot. There are 2 ways to arrange $23$ with 5 places to put them in. Then there are 4 free spaces. So in fact we have the $15$ permutations above with the $2(4)(5)$ permutations we found now which fives us a total of $55$ permutations.

Comment: It must be 5 different places according to your interpretation

Comment: Your answer is incorrect.  You have to place both a $23$ or $32$ and a $3$ in those five spaces and one of those five spaces could contain a $323$.

Comment: There are actually a total of $55$ permutations with a $3$ next to a $2$.  Of these, there are $5$ containing the block $233$, five containing the block $323$, and five containing the block $332$.  There are $20$ in which the block $23$ is separated from the other $3$ by at least one $1$ (choose one of the five spaces in your diagram for the block $23$ and one of the four remaining spaces for the single $3$).  There are also $20$ in which the block $32$ is separated from the other $3$ by at least one $1$ (using the same reasoning as above).